# Connector Identification: Flex Ribbon E-Paper Connector (Kindle 3G)

Tags: connector, identification

This connector can be found on a Kindle 3G's display (which itself is sold as Part Number ED060SC7), but I'd like to interface with it, so i need the matching socket.

Dimensions:

- plastic body is about 8,5mm (0.335") wide (long side)
- all contacts combined are about 7mm (0,276") wide
- there are 34 pins (perhaps 36 if the ones at the ends count?).
- which would give them a distance pin-to-pin of about 0,4mm (~0.016")
- length is about 1,5mm (0.06")
- height (above flex-board-surface) is ~1mm (~0.04")

[image]

I would like to know the name of the part and who manufactures these. Extra points if somebody knows of a breakout to something tinker-friendly!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

mezzanine connector

used to connect boards together in a layered fashion

this one is Panasonic AXT434124

mates with AXT334124

https://ca.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Panasonic/AXT334124

found by searching for technical drawings of ED060SC7

here is a breakout board that you could use (you would have to solder the connector)

[https://www.amazon.com/Schmartboard-SOP-0-4mm-Pitch-Version/dp/B00OGLBA6C/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1514326345&sr=8-8&keywords=SchmartBoard+0.4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OGLBA6C)

Comment: thank you very much! More than I could have asked for :-)

Comment: looking for technical drawings of the whole assembly didn't come to my mind! I found a PDF and it's amazingly useful :-) Thanks again!